# read fifo: why is it blocking then non-blocking

Tags: c++, c, server, fifo

I'm using FIFO to make two processes communicate.

```
//client:
const char * msg = "Hello, I'm cleint1.";
const char * fifoName = "../server/fifo.tmp";
int fd = open(fifoName, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, msg, strlen(msg) + 1);
close(fd);



//server:
char msg[100];
const char * fifoName = "fifo.tmp";
mkfifo(fifoName, 0666);
int fd = open(fifoName, O_RDONLY);
while(read(fd, msg, 100) > 0)
{
    std::cout<<"msg received: "<<msg<<std::endl;
}
close(fd);
unlink(fifoName);
```

The server will first block there to wait for some messages in `fifoName`. When some messages are coming (the client is executed), the server reads them and then the loop will finish.

I'm confused now. Because I can't figure out why the first time that the server calls `read` and it blocks there whereas when it calls `read` again and it doesn't block anymore.

I print the return value of `read` and I get 0 after receiving the first message.

What I need is to make the `read` blocking each time so that the server can receive any message as soon as some client sends messages.

Comment: You should print out strerror(errno) to see what the error is.

Comment: @SumitGemini, I print the return of `read` and I get 0.

Comment: so you want your server run infinitely? read continuously?

Comment: @SumitGemini  Yes. I just need the `read` blocks there each time and wait for the next message.

Comment: for this you can simply retry the read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply retry the read. For example

```
int iResult;

do
{
    iResult = read(fd, buffer, size);
    if (0 == iResult)
    {
           // Skip to the end of the do loop
            continue;
    }
        // Handle real errors
} while (!condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

You got 0 as an indicator there is no more data left and there will be no more data as the other side of the pipe got closed.

I presume you want the server to stick around and handle multiple clients, possibly even at the same time.

Pipes are fundamentally unsuitable for this purpose. You want to use **unix sockets** instead.

Finally, loops like this one:

```
while(read(fd, msg, 100) > 0)
{
    std::cout<<"msg received: "<<msg<<std::endl;
}
```

are fundamentally wrong. it is very easy to get an error from read due to signal arrival.

Also note you violate DRY by repeating the '100' for the buffer size as opposed to e.g. using sizeof(msg).